# Possible to run a chrome extension within another chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, google-chrome-extension

Long story short I'm looking to create a Chrome extension that will run within a site that only wants to run Internet Explorer (Oracle EBS). So far my only option has been to run IE Tab, which works fine when visiting the site. My new extension right now just runs alert("foo"); once a page loads and that works fine as well.

The new extension does not run in IE Tab though. Using IE Tab changes the URL to:

chrome-extension://IE_Tab's_extension_ID/nhc.htm#url=site_url

and nothing happens. Is there a way to run the extension within the IE tab extension? If anyone has an alternative idea as well I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: The only way is to run Chrome with a command line switch to allow extensions on chrome URLs and even then you might need to use chrome.debugger API. Might be easier to modify the ietab extension source code and use it instead.

Comment: Many thanks wOxxOm for the advice. I did start down the route of adding the CLS of "--extensions-on-chrome-urls" but it seems like it's only really allows you to use the extension on chrome:// not chrome-extension://. I'm instead going down the route of modifying the nhc.htm in the source folder for the original IE Tab to just add a <script src="foo.js></script> and I'll see how this will play out for now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, I ended up not doing much with IE tab or chrome. Placing a script into it's nhc.htm worked but ended up being slower and clunkier than my solution.

Instead I resorted to just using the old version of Chromium 44 (make sure it's Chromium, not chrome) and enabling the NPAPI in the chrome://flags/#enable-npapi. It's outdated tech, but really it's just there to occasionally run specific Java apps along with the new chrome extension, not replace their current browser.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 24 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.